# osm2pgsql error when import pbf for Nominatim DB

Tags: postgis, nominatim

I am getting the following error when running utils/setup.php in nominatim 2.1:

```
Reading in file: /storage/Library/geodata/africa-latest.osm.pbf

Processing: Node(54854k 62.1k/s) Way(4740k 8.26k/s) Relation(0 0.00/s)get_way_list failed: (7)

Arguments were: {48725024,162617539,160913750,95107659,95107632,95061927,94828942,94795314,94795281,48725023,48724896,48493347,48491792,48457398,23462217,23463574,23463575,23463577,23556792,23556834,23496195,48501117,48501200,48501201,48501202,48501381,48501375,48501379,48501377,48457182,48457183,48457186,48457403,48457198,48457202,48457177,48491809,48491797,48493349,48493348,48493350,161906130,161906134,93072207,93086913,93086923,93086924,93086919,93062967,162596086,162596088,94795372,162596089,94795354,94795273,94795305,94795303,94795351,94795355,94795375,94795358,94795370,94795380,94795278,94795381,94795250,94795368,94795378,94795307,94828944,94828939,94828937,94828935,94828940,94828948,94828941,94828951,94828938,94828936,94828949,94828934,94828950,94828952,94828947,95061929,94828946,95061931,95061930,95061926,95061928,95099314,95099312,95099311,95099313,95085072,95085071,95085075,95085076,95085070,95085074,162596087}, 
Error occurred, cleaning up
ERROR: Error executing external command: /storage/Nominatim/osm2pgsql/osm2pgsql -lsc -O     gazetteer --hstore -C 958 -P 9999 -d nominatimnew /storage/Library/geodata/africa-latest.osm.pbf
Error executing external command: /storage/Nominatim/osm2pgsql/osm2pgsql -lsc -O gazetteer --hstore -C 958 -P 9999 -d nominatimnew /storage/Library/geodata/africa-latest.osm.pbf
```

The command I'm running to do the initial import to create a new Nominatim DB is:

```
./utils/setup.php --osm-file africa-latest.osm.pbf --all
```

within the Nominatim directory.

Running osm2pgsql 0.85.0, PostgreSQL 9.3.2, PostGis 2.1.0 running on Slackware 14.1 64 Bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem. It is the problem with OSM data.

First of all, you can download old osm.pbf file and verify that everything is OK.

In my case, I use old version of libgeos lib.

```
sudo dpkg -i libc6_2.17-93ubuntu4_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libgeos-3.3.3_3.3.3-1.1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libgeos-c1_3.3.3-1.1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libgeos-dev_3.3.3-1.1_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i libc-dev-bin_2.17-93ubuntu4_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libc6-dev_2.17-93ubuntu4_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libnih1_1.0.3-4ubuntu16_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libnih-dbus1_1.0.3-4ubuntu16_amd64.deb

sudo apt-get autoremove

sudo dpkg -i libgeos-3.3.3_3.3.3-1.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libgeos++-dev_3.3.3-1.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb

cd ~/src/osm2pgsql
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the Nominatim install doesn't provide a clear error message, despite it being available. Thus, the answer could be anything.

In my case it turned out the hard disk which hosted the database had run full, so the import aborted.

When you're debugging, try running the command which Nominatim indicates has failed (in the asker's case, `/storage/Nominatim/osm2pgsql/osm2pgsql -lsc -O gazetteer --hstore -C 958 -P 9999 -d nominatimnew /storage/Library/geodata/africa-latest.osm.pbf`) manually to track down the error.